# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ItsDangerous==1.0.0. Django, Pythonanywhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

When I try to deploy my application to pythonanywhere, the following error
it is returned.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ItsDangerous==1.0.0

How can I solve it? I tried to change the versions to a higher one or add other packages (as per the internet tips), but to no avail.

My requirements file.

```
absl-py==0.7.1
aiourllib==0.1.3
appdirs==1.4.3
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astor==0.7.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
bleach==3.0.2
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.9.103
botocore==1.12.103
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2018.10.15
cffi==1.12.2
chardet==3.0.4
civis==1.9.0
civis-jupyter-extensions==0.1.3
civis-jupyter-notebook==0.4.2
click==6.7
cloudpickle==0.6.1
colorama==0.4.0
confusable-homoglyphs==3.2.0
crypto==1.4.1
cryptography==2.6.1
cssselect==1.0.3
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.3.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==2.0
django-bootstrap3==11.0.0
django-bower==5.2.0
django-ckeditor==5.6.1
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-debug-toolbar==1.9.1
django-filter==2.0.0
django-filters==0.2.1
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-multiselectfield==0.1.8
django-registration==2.4.1
django-scheduler==0.8.7
django-storages==1.7.1
django-taggit==0.23.0
django-tinymce==2.8.0
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.3
djangorestframework==3.9.0
docutils==0.14
entrypoints==0.2.3
fake-useragent==0.1.11
Flask==1.0.2
gast==0.2.2
gitdb2==2.0.5
GitPython==2.1.11
grpcio==1.19.0
h5py==2.9.0
httplib2==0.11.3
icalendar==4.0.3
idna==2.7
ipykernel==5.1.0
ipython==6.2.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.4.2
ItsDangerous==1.0.0
jedi==0.13.1
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.4
joblib==0.11
jsonref==0.1
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
kiwisolver==1.0.1
lxml==4.2.5
Markdown==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==3.0.3
mistune==0.8.4
Naked==0.1.31
nbconvert==5.4.0
nbformat==4.4.0
notebook==5.7.0
numpy==1.15.2
pandas==0.23.4
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parse==1.9.0
parso==0.3.1
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==5.3.0
prometheus-client==0.4.2
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
protobuf==3.7.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
pubnub==4.1.2
PyAutoGUI==0.9.41
pybase62==0.4.0
pycparser==2.19
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycryptodome==3.8.0
pycryptodomex==3.6.6
pyee==5.0.0
PyGetWindow==0.0.3
Pygments==2.2.0
PyMsgBox==1.0.6
pyparsing==2.2.2
pyppeteer==0.0.25
pyquery==1.4.0
PyRect==0.1.4
PyScreeze==0.1.19
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-decouple==3.1
PyTweening==1.0.3
pytz==2018.5
pywinpty==0.5.4
PyYAML==3.13
pyzmq==17.1.2
qtconsole==4.4.2
requests==2.20.0
requests-html==0.9.0
s3transfer==0.2.0
scipy==1.1.0
seaborn==0.9.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
shellescape==3.4.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.11.0
smmap2==2.0.5
sqlparse==0.2.4
tensorboard==1.12.2
tensorflow==1.12.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.4.2
tornado==5.1.1
tqdm==4.27.0
traitlets==4.3.2
Unidecode==1.0.23
urllib3==1.24
virtualenv==16.0.0
w3lib==1.19.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
websockets==6.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
widgetsnbextension==3.4.2
win-unicode-console==0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CHANGES file](https://github.com/pallets/itsdangerous/blob/ea267c1d3b16cf1fffd3c21d0ea174fc8bcbe73c/CHANGES.rst#version-100), the 1.0.0 release was yanked, and is no longer available.

Try switching to 1.1.0, which [is available on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/itsdangerous/#history):

```
itsdangerous==1.1.0
```